# Why the Seebeck coefficient of platinum/palladium/tungsten changes sign when temperature rises from 0 K?

Tags: thermoelectricity

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient) and this paper: Cusack, N.; Kendall, P. (1958). "The Absolute Scale of Thermoelectric Power at High Temperature". Proceedings of the Physical Society. 72 (5): 898. What mechanism is related to this phenomenon? Is it phonon drag or spin or something else?

Comment: Related - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457656/charge-carriers-type-contradiction-between-hall-effect-and-seebeck-effect-how/457913#457913

Comment: I’ve read this page before and the anomalous Seebeck of Cu Ag Au is different. They’re positive at all the temperature. No sign change occurs.

Comment: But it does for Li, as noted in that answer. Go read the cited paper.

Comment: You mean this cited paper https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.112.196603

Comment: In this paper, there are three sources of Lithium's Seebeck measured. Only one changes its sign, and its tendency doesn't match with the other two. This only source is a paper published in 1924. In this 1924 paper, many other alkali were measured and have sign reverse too, which is not the case from modern experiments.