# Hall coefficient for metals negative

Tags: solid-state-physics, metals

I am wondering why the Hall coefficient for Al is negative, I am thinking about holes (I understand how holes word in semiconductors, but I can not use that because metals have no bandgap...), but I don't find any information about holes in metals, why is that coefficient negative? And how can I interpret that?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457656/charge-carriers-type-contradiction-between-hall-effect-and-seebeck-effect-how May be useful.

Comment: @JonCuster I don't see how I could use the Seebeck effect here, can you help?

Comment: The Hall effect is discussed in my answer.